# JQuery click event works only once, <iframe> update

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using slick.js to scrollable list. When click to URL, iframe updates once.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="videoLive clearfix" id="videoSlide" role="tablist">
<li>
    <a class="changeVideo" data-yt-video="https://mover.uz/video/embed/1VZp5pTm/">Click me!</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="changeVideo" data-yt-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/P3z7Vprxwx0">Click me 2!</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="video-container" id="video01" data-current-video="https://mover.uz/video/embed/1VZp5pTm/">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://mover.uz/video/embed/1VZp5pTm/" class=liveVideo allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var videoElement = $('#video01');
$('.changeVideo').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var parentli = $this.parent('li');
    parentli.siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    var videourl = $this.data('yt-video');
    if(videoElement.data('current-video') !== videourl){
        videoElement.html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="' + videourl + '" class="liveVideo" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>');
        videoElement.attr('data-current-video', videourl);
        parentli.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

the trouble is that on('click') only works once, didn't update twice. What am I doing wrong?

Additional info: Jquery ver. 3.4.1; working with Yii2. No errors on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is how you are attempting to assign a new value to `data-current-video`:

`videoElement.attr('data-current-video', videourl);`

change to:

`videoElement.data('currentVideo', videourl);`

jQuery uses the HTML `data-` attribute for initial GET only. To SET, you need to use the `.data()` method.

> Since jQuery 1.4.3, data-* attributes are used to initialize jQuery data. An element's data-* attributes are retrieved the first time the data() method is invoked upon it, and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all values are stored internally by jQuery).

https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Answer (score -1):

You may use the bind function

```
    $('li').bind( "click", function () {
        console.log("click")
    });
```

You may change the selector as you wish.

[See the Pen](https://codepen.io/mulli/pen/ymJaQW/)